# Identifying Matched Pairs in R

Tags: r, matching

So I have installed the `Matching` package and am very new to it.
Working through the example in `Match` category, I am a little lost as to how one is able to output the resultant matched ID's of the case and control

through `head(rr$weights, n=10)` we see that for the first 'treatment' case we have 2 'control' cases matched, for the second treatmetn we have 1 control, for the third treatment we have 4 controls etc..

How is one able to output the IDs of these matched pairs?

The value `rr$mdata`outputs results in terms of the matching parameters/criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your goal, you should be able to use these statements to return the rows that end up in the Match outcome.  "m1" in this case is the result from Match() and Y was the outcome vector that was used in Match() as well.  So this gives you two vectors of the outcome variable for example.

```
treated.out <- Y[m1$index.treated]
control.out <- Y[m1$index.control]
```

Check Matching help for index.treated and index.control.